# How to get <mat-radio-group> selected value in typescript file on SAVE button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have below radio button in my html

```
 <mat-radio-group aria-label="Availability for joining" formControlName="availabilityGroup">
          <mat-radio-button value="1" [checked]='true'>Immediate</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="2">1 Month Notice</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="3">3 Month Notice</mat-radio-button>
 </mat-radio-group>
```

I need to get the user **selected** radio button value in my **typescript** file when user click **SAVE** button

How do i do it?

Comment: You should not use the `[checked]` attribute along with Reactive Forms, instead you should set the form control value accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). It looks like you have a [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls) containing this control, which is probably set up somewhat like this:

```
@Component()
export class MyComponent {
  public formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    availabilityGroup: new FormControl()
  });
  ...
}
```

In this case, you can get the value of the selected radio button with the following code:

```
this.formGroup.controls.availabilityGroup.value;
```

Comment: So you mean in my typescript i have declared this.fb.group previously as "userForm = this.fb.group({availabilityGroup: nulll}) as i need to change it as userForm = this.fb.group({availabilityGroup: new FormControl})" ?

Comment: Yes as you said I checked with my above comment. Its working. Thanks...:) I have some other input types like <input matInput in my form. So right now i am using this.userForm.get('title').value; to get its value. So do i need to change them also as you suggested, what you think?

Comment: @NithinPaul You can also use `fb.control` instead of `FormControl`.